# Splitting dots into separate objects javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object like this:

```
var data = {"prop.health": 1, "prop.cost":1, "prop.time":1}
```

I want to change it into an object like this:

```
{
  "prop": {
    "health": 1, 
    "cost":1, 
    "time":1
  }
}
```

Here's my code:

```
  _.each(data, function (value, key) {
    var split = key.split('.')
    if (split.length > 1) {
      data[split[0]] = data[split[0]] || {}
      data[split[0]][split[1]] = value
      delete data[key]
    }
  })
```

But this only works for 1 level of nesting. How would you write it to ensure it works for as deeply nested properties as you need?

Comment: How does nested look? `prop.test.fun`??

Comment: @epascarello `{'prop':{'test': {'fun': 1}}}`

Comment: Is that underscore or lodash you are using?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace lodash

Comment: Not sure if this helps but lodash can create nested objects from dot notation strings. https://lodash.com/docs#set

Comment: But why would you have/save the object like that? What is the benefit of it, if I may ask, just curiousity :p

Comment: @RensTillmann I've used to before to keep client side view models synced with a server side object and just had it pass the object path and value down to me and from that server side path update my client side view model.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Ok thanks, i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`_.transform`](https://lodash.com/docs#transform) and [`_.set`](https://lodash.com/docs#set), for example

```
data = _.transform(data, function(transformed, val, key) {
    _.set(transformed, key, val);
});
```

Results in

```
{"prop":{"health":1,"cost":1,"time":1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a library it would be something like this:

```js
(function(){
    var data = {"prop.health": 1, "prop.cost":1, "prop.time":1, "prop.test.fun" : 1, "prop.test.sun" : 1};
    var obj = {};  //will hold the object all parsed out
    Object.keys(data).forEach( function (key) {  //loop through the keys in the object
        var val = data[key];  //grab the value of this key
        var step = obj;  //reference the object that holds the values
        key.split(".").forEach(function(part, index, arr){   //split the parts and loop
            if(index===arr.length-1){  //If we are at the last index, than we set the value
                step[part] = val;
            } else if(step[part]===undefined) {  //If we have not seen this key before, create an object
                step[part] = {};
            }
            step = step[part];  //Step up the object we are referencing 
        });
    } );
    console.log(obj);
}());
```

Or the double reduce loop

```js
(function(){
    var data = {"prop.health": 1, "prop.cost":1, "prop.time":1, "prop.test.fun" : 1, "prop.test.sun" : 1};
    var result = Object.keys(data).reduce( function (obj, key) {  //loop through the keys in the object
        var val = data[key];  //grab the value of this key
        key.split(".").reduce(function(step, part, index, arr){   //split the parts and loop
            if(index===arr.length-1){  //If we are at the last index, than we set the value
                step[part] = val;
            } else if(step[part]===undefined) {  //If we have not seen this key before, create an object
                step[part] = {};
            }
            return step[part];  //Step up the object we are referencing
        }, obj);
        return obj;
    }, {});
    console.log(result);
}());
```

Comment: Aww, no `Array.prototype.reduce` ;)

Comment: LOL, I am playing with a reduce version right now. :)

Comment: @Phil Happy now? Probably even other ways of doing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on a number of factors (e.g. if the original object always has keys you want to delete, etc.) you may be able to use [`_.set`](https://lodash.com/docs#set):

```
var data = {"prop.health": 1, "prop.cost":1, "prop.time":1};

_.each(data, function (value, key) {
  delete data[key];
  _.set(data, key, value);
});
```

`_.set` will create the path if it doesn't exist. The above results in:

```
{"prop":{"health":1,"cost":1,"time":1}}
```

And `{"prop.health": 1, "prop.cost.food":1, "prop.time":1}` will result in:

```
{"prop":{"health":1,"cost":{"food":1},"time":1}}
```